# read filename with sign ( + and - )

Tags: python, regex, special-characters, readfile

I have a code that scan the folder for filename by this line:

```
  fileNum = re.findall(r'T([0.-999.])\.txt',inputName)
```

This correctly reads the files that I have with this type of name: T12.txt, T13.3.txt.

Now I have some files that contains also special character + and - in the file name: T13_B+14.txt, T13_B-15.txt,T13_B0.0.txt etc (the only variable is the B factor with sign). To include + sign as special character of reading, I modify the line as this:

```
  fileNum = re.findall(r'T13_B[\w+]([0.-99.])\.txt',inputName)
```

This now correctly reads the file with + in the file name. So I have to do separate running for + and - .

Q: How can I include any character in the filename for reading ( like here [\w+] ) ?

Comment: It seems there are many different file name formats that you need to match. Notably with the `_B` variation (according to your examples, with optional sign after B, optional `.digit` at the end -- and/or in the middle?) Depending of the content of your directory, if there is _no_ risk of confusion, wouldn't `^T.+\.txt` simply do the trick? Otherwise, please edit your question with a _complete_ list of all the different variations in order for us to provide a really _matching_ regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your currient regular experssion would match every input string. You forgot to mask the dots, so you would accept every charactor.

For accepting the chars `T`, `B`, `0`, `1`, [...], `9`, `+`, `-`, `_` you need to use this regular expression:

```
^T[\dB\._+-]+\.txt$
```

However as pointed out in the comments Reza needed in this case is another regular expression:

```
^T13_B[\d\.+-]+\.txt$
```

This one accepts all files prefixed by `T13_B` and followed by any number, dot, plus and minus sign and the suffix `.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, seems very close. but i do not get exactly this form: T13_B+14.txt by putting T13_B[\d+-].txt (it is not exactly your command as it didnt work also for this example)

Comment: There you need to mask the dot again and you missed a plus sign for allowing multiple chars: `T13_B[\d+-]+\.txt`

Comment: great, just 1 thing: \d works just with integer or e.g 13.4? I have actually always with the format of one digit.

Comment: \d is an alias for 0-9 so it is some like int. For supporting that decimal dot you need to add a masked dot: [\d\.+-]

Comment: I don not agree with the given regex `^T[\dB\._+-]+\.txt$` because it matches any filename starting with a T followed by one or many digit , letter 'B' underscore or plus/minus sign in any order. This match for example TBBBBB.txt with obviously does not have the required format. BTW, the _dot_ does not have to be protected when it appears in a set of characters `[.]`.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux the orginal regex was extended in the comments. The final version is now: `^T13_B[\d\.+-]+\.txt$`. Do I really need to add this to my answer above? The part of the dot is new for me do you have a reference?

Comment: @rekire Please edit your answer to the latest solution -- this is especially important as it is the _accepted_ answer. BTW, it does not match the given file name `T12.txt`...

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to match everything of the form `Tdigits` then possibly other characters until `.txt`.  So just match that as a regex

```
fileNum = re.findall(r'^T\d+.+\.txt',inputName)
```

Answer (score 1):

`[0.-99.]` is not what you think. It means one of characters `09.` or one in the range `.-9`, which is `./0123456789`. To match one or two digits, use `\d{1,2}` or `\d\d?`. To match the `\w` characters or `+` or `-` use `[\w+-]`.